# Automapper - Flatten with list at the same time

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a view model that I've received from the client which looks something like this

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public string ContactDetails {get;set;}
     public List<FunkyThing_ViewModel> {get;set;}
}

public class FunkyThing_ViewModel
{
    public string ThingName{get;set;}
    public string Colour{get;set;}
    public string Size{get;set;}
}
```

I wish to map this to a list of domain models where each which looks something more like this:

```
public class Order
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string ContactDetails {get;set;}
   public string ThingName{get;set;}
   public string Colour{get;set;}
   public string Size{get;set;}
}
```

So I'm wanting do end up with something that looks like this:

```
List<Order> orders = new Orders();
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderViewModel, List<Order>>();
//Something in here to ensure each funky thing creates an additional order....

Mapper.Map(viewModel, orders);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you can accomplish this when the `Order` class has no public setters for it's members...

Comment: Apologies there privates are mistake, they are of course all meant to be public - amended....

Comment: ...although just to point out that AutoMapper can handle private members too, you would use `Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.BindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
});`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;
using NUnit.Framework;
using SharpTestsEx;

namespace StackOverflowExample.Automapper
{
    public class OrderViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ContactDetails { get; set; }
        public List<FunkyThingViewModel> FunkyThingViewModels { get; set; }
    }

    public class FunkyThingViewModel
    {
        public string ThingName { get; set; }
        public string Colour { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ContactDetails { get; set; }
        public string ThingName { get; set; }
        public string Colour { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class FlattenWithListTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void FlattenListTest()
        {
            //arrange
            var source = new OrderViewModel
                {
                    Name = "name",
                    ContactDetails = "contact",
                    FunkyThingViewModels = new List<FunkyThingViewModel>
                        {
                            new FunkyThingViewModel {Colour = "red"},
                            new FunkyThingViewModel {Colour = "blue"}
                        }
                };

            Mapper.CreateMap<FunkyThingViewModel, Order>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<OrderViewModel, Order>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<OrderViewModel, List<Order>>()
                  .ConvertUsing(om => om.FunkyThingViewModels.Select(
                      ftvm =>
                          {
                              var order = Mapper.Map<Order>(om);
                              Mapper.Map(ftvm, order);
                              return order;
                          }).ToList());

            //act
            var mapped = Mapper.Map<List<Order>>(source);

            //assert
            mapped[0].Satisfy(m =>
                              m.Name == source.Name &&
                              m.ContactDetails == source.ContactDetails &&
                              m.Colour == "red");
            mapped[1].Satisfy(m =>
                              m.Name == source.Name &&
                              m.ContactDetails == source.ContactDetails &&
                              m.Colour == "blue");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd have never got there!  Excellent - Thanks Sunny!

Comment: how do you even come up with something like this? :)

Comment: how would you do this using the Profile base class?

Comment: Depends what you mean by Profile class. If you use the static mapper in your code, it stays the same. If on the other hand you use more advanced (and proper) IoC injection of IMappingEngine, etc, then create a custom resolver for OrderViewModel->List<Order>, in which you can inject the same mapping engine and use itside.

Comment: They asked that because Mapper.Map can not be easily used in a Profile class. It requires configuration which makes using that inside a ConvertUsing not a great solution.